# Plot $Im(\zeta(s))=0$ in complex plane

Tags: complex-analysis, riemann-zeta

I am interested to find any graphic representation of this trajectories in complex plane:

$$\Im(\zeta(s))=0$$

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Sure, the mathematica command

```
ComplexPlot[Im[Zeta[s]], {s, -10 - 10 I, 10 + 10 I}, 
 PlotLegends -> Automatic]
```

Does it and produces the plot below (notice that the color corresponds to the argument, so red is positive, and blue(?) is negative. I am not sure how much of the complex plane you want, but this is in the square with vertices at $-10 - 10 i$ and $10+10 i.$

[image]

Comment: @Diger For God's sake, read the answer. It explains that the positive part is red, and the negative is blue. So zero is the boundary between them.

Comment: Sorry... Didn't notice. But Thanks